# Sweet spot for StackOverflow reputation (in which range do you acquire most points?)

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

If I'd like to get most reputation points possible - **to immediately spend them as bounty on my programming questions** - what would be the best range to be in?

For example 1000-2000 seems to be better than 2000-3000. Because in the former range when you edit posts, they are reviewed and you get +2 for each accepted edit. While this doesn't happen in the latter range.

So what range is the best? Do upvotes on questions/answers bring more points in 100-1000 range?

Comment: I've heard a [Guide to Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51285/203972) is being published soon that might be a useful resource.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know that there really is a "sweet spot" for reputation on Stack Overflow. It may seem better to be in the 1000-2000 range because of the +2 bonus for suggested edits, but you can only gain 1000 reputation total from edits, so there's no benefit to going back (by posting bounties) once you've passed that range.

> Do upvotes on questions/answers bring more points in 100-1000 range?

No, everyone gets the same +5 reputation for question upvotes and +10 for answer upvotes. (Until you hit the daily reputation cap of 200, which is also the same at any reputation level.)

Comment: +1: I'd also add that in a community like this, you don't _need_ to spend all your reputation points on bounty. It might draw attention to the question, but if your question is well worded and researched, it _will_ get attention.